# Set delay for retrofit api calls using rxjava2

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

I'm trying to replace `Handler` with `RxJava2`. I want to make `apiCall()` to backend every 800ms, but it does not work with `delay`

**PRESENTER**

```
val disposable = repository.apiCall(...)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .toObservable()
                .throttleFirst(800, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .subscribe({ result ->
                    ...
                }, { _ ->
                    ...
                })
        compositeDisposable.add(disposable)
```

**REPO**

```
fun apiCall(...): Single<ArrayList<Data>> {
    return service.retrofitCall(...)
            .onErrorResumeNext(...)
            .map { result ->
                ...
                return@map result 
            }
}
```

This made like alot of requests. Feeled like a loop lol. What I need is every 800ms this api call sends request (in case user spam click button)

**SCENERIO**

User presses button and that calls api request. I want to make sure, if user spam clicks this button, only 1 request call goes to api, not 100x. I think this could be done with `debounce` in past.

Comment: So you want to call `service.apiCall()` repeatedly and have a single flow of those data lists?

Comment: That's a completely different requirement. Have you actually tried `debounce` or `throttleFirst`?

Comment: @akarnokd Sorry, that might have been misleading. Can u update your answer please, and show how you would achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: (change in the actual question)

Take a [stream of clicks](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding#rxbinding), throttle it and flatMap the API call onto it

```
fun setup() {
    clicksDisposable = RxView.clicks(button)
    .throttleFirst(800, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
    .flatMapSingle({ t ->
        service.apiCall()
        .onErrorResumeNext(...)
        .map { result -> result   }
    })
    .subscribe(/* ... */);
}
```

Comment: I updated my original post, take a look please. I used your scenerio and this made alot of requests.

Comment: That's what you asked for. 800 milliseconds is 0.8 seconds, so you'll get 5 requests per 4 seconds.

Comment: Well, if I try to use your syntax on my example `apiCall()` in `REPO` (example above), then it doesn't find a command as `throttleFirst`

Comment: `throttleFirst` is an operator on [`Observable`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#throttleFirst-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-). Please provide **exactly** what you have done that doesn't work.

Comment: I edited original post. Basically I try to convert single to observable using `toObservable()` and then call `throttleFirst`. Syntax point of view - everything seems to be okay, but api requests doesnt pause 800ms between them.

Comment: You have to throttle the button clicks and not create an api call Single on each invocation of that click handler. Looks like there is a misunderstanding about the structure of your code. Please provide the activity parts where you handle your button clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at .repeatWhen()

You can maybe use something like

```
fun apiCall(): Single<ArrayList<Data>> {
  return service.apiCall()
        .repeatWhen(completed -> completed.delay(800, MILLISECONDS)))
        .onErrorResumeNext(...)
        .map { result->

        }
}
```

Comment: You have to change the return type to `Flowable<ArrayList<Data>>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to repeat the request, you have to use interval:

```
fun apiCall(): Single<ArrayList<Data>> {
    return Observable.interval(800, 800, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .flatmap { service.apiCall() }
            .onErrorResumeNext(...)
            .map { result->

            }
}
```

Comment: `interval` is a static method and will have no relation to the apiCall before it. Also the return type has to change.